# Remove border space area of WPF piechart

Tags: wpf, templates, charts, wpftoolkit

Afternoon All,

[image: blank area]

I am trying to remove the extra blank area as show in the attached picture.
After doing some research I found most of the answer here...

[How to give Style to WPF Toolkit Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184501/how-to-give-style-to-wpf-toolkit-chart)

It basically edits the template for the piechart and removes the border I want to get rid of.
The problem is, it also removes the datapoint labels with the arrows and percentages.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of the spacing... but also keep my datapoint labels?

Thank!

Comment: That answer is almost correct. But instead of commenting the `<Border...` tag you could rather leave the tag and change the property `BorderThickness="0"`

Comment: I made the border thickness 0 and it removed the actual border line, but the datapoint labels are still not being displayed.

Comment: Basically, as soon as I edit the chart.style, it automatically removes the datapoint labels